# Python lightweight-charts bars from tick data in real-time

Tags: python, yfinance, lightweight-charts

My goal is to upload live data. So far I have only been able to have static data on the chart. I have historical data in df = tic.history(period="1y") and data in
data = yf.download( now how do I make panda read in df1 and df2 and have live candles
reference: https://github.com/louisnw01/lightweight-charts-python

```
   tic = yf.Ticker('EURUSD=X')
    df = tic.history(period="1y")

    df = df.reset_index()
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()


    
    data = yf.download('EURUSD=X', start="2023-11-01", end=None, period='15m')[['Open',      'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]

    df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/cilincilin/lightweight_chart/ohlc.csv')
    
    # Columns: time | price 
    df2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/cilincilin/lightweight_chart/ticks.csv')
    

    
    chart.set(df1)
    
    chart.show()
    
    for i, tick in df2.iterrows():
        chart.update_from_tick(tick)
            
        sleep(0.03)
```

```
Sorry, I'm new to Python, I hope you can help me.
```